# Need to pass back customer values to a POST action in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, onclick

I have a form that displays customer data based on a JSON object received from an initial GET request. I map that information out to display both the customer details and their available offers and I've created an onClick function to highlight their selected offer which maps offerId to an object I've defined in state called `cardActive`. What I'm trying to do now is create a second onClick function connected to a submit button that fires a POST action returning the following values as the JSON body:

```
{
  "CustomerId" : "1",
  "SessionId" : "9636",
  "Offer": {
    "OfferId" : "1",
    "OfferName" : "Business Internet 75"
  }
}
```

I've included my current component below including a dummy JSON object that mimics the response back from that initial GET request

```
class UsersList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.selectCard = this.selectCard.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cardActive: null,
      offerName: null,
      customerId: null,
      customers: [
        {
          CustomerId: "1",
          LastName: "Doe",
          FirstName: "Jane",
          Address: {
            Address1: "1811 Chestnut Street",
            Address2: null,
            City: "Philadelphia",
            State: "Pennsylvania",
            Zip: "19103"
          },
          Offers: [
            {
              OfferId: "Offer1",
              Name: "Offer Number 1",
              Products: [
                {
                  ProductId: 1,
                  ProductName: "Cool stuff"
                },
                {
                  ProductId: 2,
                  ProductName: "Some little stuff"
                }
              ],
              Price: "$1"
            },
            {
              OfferId: "Offer2",
              Name: "Offer Number 2",
              Price: "$2",
              Products: [
                {
                  ProductId: 3,
                  ProductName: "More stuff"
                },
                {
                  ProductId: 4,
                  ProductName: "Hey theres stuff here"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              OfferId: "Offer3",
              Name: "Offer Number 3",
              Price: "$3",
              Products: [
                {
                  ProductId: 5,
                  ProductName: "Check out this stuff"
                },
                {
                  ProductId: 5,
                  ProductName: "More stuff"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  selectCard(offerId) {
    this.setState({ cardActive: offerId });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.customers.map((customer, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index + customer.CustomerId}>
              <h3>
                Name: {customer.LastName}, {customer.FirstName}
              </h3>
              <h3>Customer ID: {customer.CustomerId}</h3>
              <h3>
                Address:
                <br />
                {customer.Address.Address1}
                <br />
                {customer.Address.City}, {customer.Address.State}{" "}
                {customer.Address.Zip}
              </h3>
              <br />
              <h2>Available Offers</h2>
              <Grid container spacing={24} justify="center">
                {customer.Offers.map((Offer, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={index + Offer.OfferId}
                      onClick={() => this.selectCard(Offer.OfferId)}
                    >
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <div
                          className={
                            Offer.OfferId === this.state.cardActive
                              ? "cardActive"
                              : "card"
                          }
                        >
                          <div className="container">
                            <h5>
                              <b>{Offer.OfferId}</b>
                            </h5>
                            <h2>{Offer.Name}</h2>
                            {Offer.Products.map((Product, index) => {
                              return (
                                <div key={index + Product.ProductId}>
                                  <p>+ {Product.ProductName}</p>
                                </div>
                              );
                            })}
                            <h3>{Offer.Price}</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Grid>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </Grid>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button className="navbuttonSelected">Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UsersList;
```

I added the objects into the state that I'm hoping to populate (offerName, CustomerId and keeping cardActive as the holder for offerId) and now I'm trying to figure out how to write the function to map all of those values to send back via POST. The best I've come up with so far is

```
submitSelection(offerId, offerName, CustomerId) {
  this.setState({
    cardActive: offerId,
    offerName: offerName,
    CustomerId,
    SessionId: SessionId
  });
}
```

Any suggestions/examples on how to do this would be a huge help

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you came up with?

Comment: I updated my submitSelection function to `submitSelection(offerId, offerName, CustomerId, SessionId, ){
        this.setState({ cardActive: offerId, offerName: offerName, CustomerId: CustomerId, SessionId: SessionId });
        console.log(this.cardActive, this.offerName, this.CustomerId, this.SessionId);
    }` attached the function to an onClick event and tested it in browser but it returns `undefined undefined undefined undefined`

Comment: Something like the following?
`this.state = {
            response: {
                  cardActive: null,
                  offerName: null,
                  customerId: null,
                  sessionId: null
            }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to handle the data form is by a state property in this case will be something like this :

```
this.state = {
       dataModel:{
         cardActive : null,
         offerName  : null,
         customerId : null,
         CustomerId : null,
         SessionId  : null,
       },
       ...
       }
      ]
    };
```

So in your submit function you can just update the data that youve received to the `this.state.dataModel`.

then you can use axios or somthing to send the dataModel to as the data of the axios method.

Check my sandbox maybe is clearer that way:

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xm00xplm2

Comment: I tried to implement this but it's failing at `this.submitData = () => {let temporalDataModel = this.state.dataModel;
            (temporalDataModel.cardActive = this.state.offerId),` that first statement setting the offerId fails with the following error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

Comment: I tried it in the sandbox and it pushed to console and listed the data model but everything is showing as undefined still

Comment: Ive updated the code sand box it was missing the implementation of the update data form and other stuff. You have to giveparameters to search and populate the data form correctly, in this case you use customer id and offer id.

Comment: I'm using it now and it looks great but everytime I hit submit the only parameter that sends is customerId. Where do I add the logic to pass the selected offer data back to the object for sending?

Comment: The *selectCard* method is the one that assigns the values to the form data, i was doing it twice, so that's what was wrong with my code. I've deleted the update before the submit. Now you just need to add a sessionId it could be initialized in a componentDidMount method. to just do it once

Comment: So inside the _selectCard_ method I can set the values like `this.setState({ cardActive: obj.offerId,  SessionId: obj.SessionId, offerId: Offer.OfferId, offerName: Offer.OfferName });` ?

Comment: Nevermind think I got it! The only issue I'm having now is that I can't seem to set the Session ID

Comment: You can set the Session id in a method called ```componentDidMount```, this will allow you to set the session after the app is mounted. check this if you need to understand how it works. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html in the section *Adding Lifecycle Methods to a Class
*

Comment: If I grab the data from an external API, can I create a function outside of state and call it in a `componentDidMount()` like so: `getCustomers(){
            axios.get("htttps://myAPI.com/getCustomers")
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        customers: response.data.customers,
                        SessionId: response.data.customers.SessionId,
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                })
        
                .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false}))
        }`

Comment: Yes, that is the way you should do it, only once after the component is mounted

Comment: Ok so I create the `getCustomers()` method and then call it inside componentDidMount() like so: `componentDidMount(){ getCustomers(); }`

Comment: Yes and if in any case you need to update your costumers data you just call the method

Comment: Ok I implemented and ran it and even though I had `getCustomers()` defined outside of state and before my `componentDidMount()` method it said that `getCustomers()` is not defined. My `componentDidMount()` looks like `componentDidMount(){ getCustomers() }` Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: maybe you have to use  ```this.getCostumers()``` it depends how you wrote the method

Comment: I used that and it seems to be working! No console errors and everything is compiling properly! I'm still waiting on the actual API endpoint to fully test, but everything seems to be green for now. Thank you!

Comment: I just received the API and the data wasn't mapping correctly so I had to hard code `this.state.customer.LastName` and so on for all of the initial display values, and now the temporalDataModel object isn't updating the dataModel object. I set up a sandbox with my current code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r7nk4vrox. Any idea why the data isn't passing from obj > temporalDataModel > dataModel ?